# ios UIPageViewController, how to remove bottom's gap?

Tags: iphone, uipagecontrol

How to remove bottom space of pageViewController?

[image]

so It can show the control icon on the image not on the black space..

Comment: Have you tried any solutions? How have they turned out?

Comment: I found a great alternative.
https://github.com/ddeville/DDPageControl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several solutions mentioned in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935887/how-to-remove-the-bottom-gap-of-uipageviewcontroller)! Here they are: Either switch the transition style from `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll` to `UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl` or implement the following code in the viewDidLoad:

```
NSArray *subviews = self.pageController.view.subviews;
UIPageControl *thisControl = nil;
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        thisControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

thisControl.hidden = true;
self.pageController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+40);
```

It will automatically hide the pageControl indicator.