# How to remove the bottom gap of UIPageViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I am using UIPageViewController to show images full screen, the UIViewController which is added to UIPageController as a sub view / child has the images being showed using ImageView. 
Problem is the images arent comming fullscreen, instead the pagecontrol view's donts are appearing at the bottom and that space is completely wasted. Please check the image attached.

[image]

Here is the code

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];

self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];

NewsItemViewController *initialViewController = [self viewControllerAtIndex:0];

NSArray *viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObject:initialViewController];

[self.pageController setViewControllers:viewControllers direction:UIPageViewControllerNavigationDirectionForward animated:NO completion:nil];

[self addChildViewController:self.pageController];
[[self view] addSubview:[self.pageController view]];
[self.pageController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Here NewsItemViewController is UIViewController showing images and some text and The MainViewController implements UIPageViewControllerDataSource protocol and necessary methods in MainViewController.

I believe there has to be a way to do show the things in full screen.

*** Also the MainViewController is a part of a storyboard if that matters.

Comment: You should use a UIPageControl and a UIScrollView instead, then you have granular control.

Comment: Show us some code regarding how you set up the page view controller.

Comment: @JohnWoods there has to be a way as UIPageViewController was supposed to replace UIPageControl and ScrollView plus I want flexibility of designing the view in xib editor which i wont get in you mentioned approach.

Comment: @bilobatum added the code please check. I am able to search the PageControl from the UIPageViewController and hide it but still that space remains there.

Comment: Ok, so the code above looks good. So we can rule that out as the problem. Let's look elsewhere. Does your NewsItemViewController contain any layout code?

Comment: @bilobatum nope its just layout using xib editor a simple UIImageView which spans entire view thats it, i was expecting the entire view to be shown but then that gap hides bottom part of image

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41079/discussion-between-bilobatum-and-vishal)

Comment: Tried removing the autolayout stuff from everywhere.

Comment: @bilobatum i m on chat

Comment: How Can we make the control indicator over the image instead of removing it. While doing as u suggested control indicator is being lost

Comment: @nischalhada make the background of the indicator view clear

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Finally got the solution myself I just hide the page control from UIViewPageController and then extended the size of the UIPageViewController to cover up the gap left due to absense of page control.

```
 NSArray *subviews = self.pageController.view.subviews;
UIPageControl *thisControl = nil;
for (int i=0; i<[subviews count]; i++) {
    if ([[subviews objectAtIndex:i] isKindOfClass:[UIPageControl class]]) {
        thisControl = (UIPageControl *)[subviews objectAtIndex:i];
    }
}

thisControl.hidden = true;
self.pageController.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, self.view.frame.size.width, self.view.frame.size.height+40);
```

Comment: Thanks for the nice solution, saved me a ton of time!

Comment: Can you make the control indicator over the image itself instead of removing it? I want that because there's no indication to the user he can swipe by removing the indicator.

Comment: @NunoGonçalves using above code you get access to the UIPageControl , you can make its background color to be clear and achieve it, basically you can customize the indicator once you get the access to it , which above shoes how to do.

Comment: @vishal I have tried your method to show the UIPageControl over the content, but it is not appearing no matter what.

Answer (score 21):

Curious. The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIPageViewControllerDataSourceProtocolRef/UIPageViewControllerDataSource.html#//apple_ref/occ/intf/UIPageViewControllerDataSource) say:

> If both of the methods in “Supporting a Page Indicator” are
>   implemented and the page view controller’s transition style is
>   UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll, a page indicator is
>   visible.

Those two methods are:

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
}

- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController { 
}
```

Are you implementing these two data source methods? If so, perhaps if you remove them you won't have to manually remove the page control (dots)? A quick test would be to change the

```
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll
```

to

```
UIPageViewControllerTransitionStylePageCurl
```

and see if the page control indicator dots go away. (After commenting out your hide method, of course.)

Comment: agree, but i need those methods , i guess they are needed to supply necessary view data when you scroll.

Comment: You were right, the page control indicator does go away if you switch to the PageCurl transition style.

Comment: Removing the two methods above, also removed the dots and gap. Success!

Comment: dots are disappering when u delte procedures "presentationCountForPageViewController" and "presentationIndexForPageViewController".

But what if u want a scenario like this >> 

 - we want to dots stay !
 - background of dots must go away !
 - scrollview inside pageviewcontrol must extent to full screen
 - background of pagecontrol must not clip the view !

Comment: Access the individual view and modify it the way i did check my answer for hint

Answer (score 14):

UIPageViewController dots are only shown when you have implemented following method:

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController;
```

check in you code. and also returning back zero in this method will hide the dots (UIPageControl)

Comment: I wanted to remove the black strip if you read carefully, the above method will just remove dots not the gap.

Comment: it does, there might be some other problem with the code. it removes the strip completely.

Answer (score 7):

I am adding for swift 2.2 compatible code

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view.isKindOfClass(UIScrollView) {
        view.frame = UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
    } else if view.isKindOfClass(UIPageControl) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
}
```

This is the Swift 4 compatible solution, embedded in `viewDidLayoutSubviews`

```
for view in self.view.subviews {
    if view.isKind(of:UIScrollView.self) {
        view.frame = UIScreen.main.bounds
    } else if view.isKind(of:UIPageControl.self) {
        view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift version :). Return Zero for below implementation inside UIPageViewController subclass.
    func presentationCountForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int { return 0 }

```
func presentationIndexForPageViewController(pageViewController: UIPageViewController) -> Int { return 0 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set your pager controller as so

```
self.pageController = [[UIPageViewController alloc] initWithTransitionStyle:UIPageViewControllerTransitionStyleScroll navigationOrientation:UIPageViewControllerNavigationOrientationHorizontal options:nil];
self.pageController.dataSource = self;
[[self.pageController view] setFrame:[[self view] bounds]];
```

And implement,this method should return any value greater than 1

```
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return 2;
}
```

Now the gap at the bottom space is removed and no page control shown :)