# Viewcontrollers going 20 pixel down when try to hide the pag control from UIPageviewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipageviewcontroller

I want to hide the bottom dots from `UIPageviewcontroller`, I successfully hide the bottom dots(Page control) by removing these methods.

```
- (NSInteger)presentationCountForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The number of items reflected in the page indicator.
    return viewCount;
}
- (NSInteger)presentationIndexForPageViewController:(UIPageViewController *)pageViewController {
    // The selected item reflected in the page indicator.
    return 0;
}
```

The problem is when i hide this, the inner content (`UIViewcontroller`) going 20 pixels down,but When i touch the view it will automatically goes 20 pixels up.How i can fix this issue?

Comment: Are you using auto layout?

Comment: yes i'm using auto layout

Comment: Ok, I think that you should resize the frame of the view of your UIPageViewController. Check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935887/how-to-remove-the-bottom-gap-of-uipageviewcontroller

Comment: @Pintouch thanks my friend. i found the solution from your given link ;)